# How do stop panels from becomming key window on launch?

Tags: cocoa

I have a xib file with a main window and a panel. On awakeFromNib I try to orderFront the main window, but the panel keeps being key window.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[inspectionPanelOutlet orderBack:self];
[inspectionPanelOutlet orderWindow:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:0];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

This code has no effect.

Comment: It is because my panel is in the same xib as the main window? should every window, dialog, and panel be in its own xib file?

Comment: IB User Guide states (pg 48):
A mistake made by many developers who are new to Interface Builder is to place all of their application’s windows and menus in these one or two nib files.

guess that answers my question

Comment: No, that's not the reason. A window and a panel in one xib is not excessive: if they are functionally related there's nothing wrong with keeping them together in one nib or xib. Once your app gets complicated you might want to group, say, all your ingredients-related windows and panels in one nib, while the recipe-related stuff goes into another.

Comment: Just to verify, we are talking about a Cocoa desktop application, not iPhone, right?

Comment: `NSWindowBelow` wouldn't exist if this were Cocoa Touch.

Comment: And putting them both in the same archive (nib) doesn't matter. It's just an archive, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure awakeFromNib is called (add an NSLog message and see if it fires)? If it is called you might want to try:

```
[self makeMainWindow];
```

or

```
[self makeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: first one crashes
2009-12-18 12:42:49.235 MacSkirmish[3034:10b] An uncaught exception was raised
2009-12-18 12:42:49.236 MacSkirmish[3034:10b] Invalid parameter not satisfying: [self canBecomeMainWindow]
2009-12-18 12:42:49.236 MacSkirmish[3034:10b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [self canBecomeMainWindow]'

second one has no effect
:(

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error. But anyway, my answer violated the principle I try to program by: Don't fix it if it ain't broke. If you select the panel in Interface Builder and look at its attributes you'll see in the section "Behavior" a checkbox named "Visible At Launch". Check this for the main window, uncheck it for the panel and remove all that stuff from the awakeFromNib. If you want to learn how to show the panel by clicking a button check out <a href="http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/FancyAbout/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000390">FancyAbout</a>.